# Comparing values across unequal matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to compare rows across two unequal matrices in Matlab and extract these rows to be stored in a different matrix (say D). For example,

```
tmp = [2245; 2345; 2290; 4576]
```

and

```
id=[1 2245 564 8890 123; 
    2 2445 5673 7846 342; 
    3 2290 3428 3321 908].
```

Id is a much larger matrix. I want to locate each value of tmp which is in ‘id’. Although using the intersect command in the line below I have been able to locate the rows of id which contain the values from tmp, I would like to do this for each value of tmp one by one as each value of tmp is repeated multiple times in id. I tried using foreach. However, I get an error message stating that foreach cannot be used for char type array. Could anyone please suggest an alternative how to go about this?

```
for j=1:length(tmp);
[D,itmp,id2] = intersect(tmp(j,1),id(:,2), 'rows');
```

Despite using the loop, the code doesn’t seem to take one value of j at a time. This was the reason behind trying ‘foreach j’. Also after finding the rows common to the two matrices and storing them in D, I would like to append matrix id to include the value of j next to the relevant row within id. For example, if the first value within tmp was repeated in id in rows 1,3,5,10; I would like a column in id which would take the value 1 next to rows 1,3,5,10. Any help on this would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly, what you trying to do, but to search a value in a matrix you can use [find](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html?nocookie=true):

```
  for i = 1:numel(tmp)        
    [row, col] = find(id == tmp(i));             
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using a combination of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html).  What you would do is transform the `tmp` vector so that it is a single 3D vector, then use the `eq` (equals) function and see which values in your matrix are equal to each value of `tmp`.  Therefore, do something like:

```
%// Your data
id=[1 2245 564 8890 123;
2 2445 5673 7846 342;
3 2290 3428 3321 908]
tmp = [2245; 2345; 2290; 4576];

tmp2 = permute(tmp, [3 2 1]); %// Make a 3D vector
tmp3 = bsxfun(@eq, id, tmp2); %// Find which locations of id are equal to each value of tmp
```

This is what I get for my final output, stored in `tmp3`:

```
tmp3(:,:,1) =

     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


tmp3(:,:,2) =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


tmp3(:,:,3) =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0


tmp3(:,:,4) =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

---

As you can see here, each 3D slice tells you which elements in `id` match the corresponding value in `tmp`.  Therefore, the first slice tells you whether any element in `id` is equal to `tmp(1)`, which is 2245.  In this case, this would be the first row and second column.  For the second slice, no values matched `tmp(2) = 2345`.  For the third slice, one value in `id` matched `tmp(3) = 2290`, which is row 3, column 3.

Now, what you're really after is determining the rows and columns of where each value of `tmp` matched each location in `id`.  You want this to be delineated per `id` number.  That can easily be done using [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) and [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) on this matrix:

```
[rows, cols, ID] = ind2sub(size(tmp3), find(tmp3))

rows =

     1
     3


cols =

     2
     2


ID =

     1
     3
```

Therefore, `ID` tells you which `id` we have matched to, and `rows`, `cols` tells you which rows and columns in `id` we were able to match with.  Therefore, for `id = 1`, we found a match with `tmp(1)= 2245`, and this is located at `row=1,col=2`.  Similarly, for `id = 3`, we found a match with `tmp(3)=2290` and this is at `row=3,col=2`.

To make this into all one big 2D matrix that contains all the information you want, you can simply concatenate all of these columns into one matrix.  Therefore:

```
final = [ID rows cols]

final =

     1     1     2
     3     3     2
```

You can read this like so:

- `id=1` with `tmp(1) = 2245`, we found this value in `row=1,col=2`.
- `id=3`, with `tmp(3) = 2290`, we found this value in `row=3,col=2`

---

Hope this helps!